# how to iteratively toggle elements in few divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

in one div i could use something like this:

```
$(".parent").find(".child").first().fadeToggle(500, function showNext() {
    $( this ).next( ".child" ).fadeToggle( 500, showNext );
});
```

But it works only for first parent div, how to toggle all child divs?

Comment: remove `first()` and it toggles all of them, it's sorta in the name, *"it get's the first element in the collection only"*

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".child:visible:first").fadeToggle(500, function showNext() {
    $(".child:visible:first").fadeToggle( 500, showNext );
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4F77F/)**

Comment: i want to one iteration not two different

Comment: What do you mean you "want to one iteration"? I don't understand what that means.

Comment: your code iterates and toggles childs in all parents at the same time. I want to toggle all childs inside first parrent, then toggle all childs inside next parrent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var $children = $(".parent .child"),
    index = 0;

$children.eq(index).fadeToggle(700, function showNext() {
    if (++index < $children.length) {
        $children.eq(index).fadeToggle( 700, showNext );
    }
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N9tz5/